# How can I setup one set of API's across multiple URI's?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, rest, routes

For our web app I want to let developers create accounts using our api, when an account is created the URI has a subdomain. To accomplish this, do I have to have two separate API's because the URL is different.

For account creation: api.example.com/v1

For account usage: subdomain.example.com/api/v1/

we are using .net mvc3, can this be done with one set of api's and routes?

Answer (score 0):

You should set up routing to get to the relevant controller+action as usual, and inside an action (or much better - using an ActionFilter), examine the subdomain and set the appropriate code that determines the who the user is, for further handling.

Example of a filter would be:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class SubdomainFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        int? userID = null;

        Uri uri = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url;
        if (uri != null)
        {
            string domain = uri.Host;
            // do whatever you need analyzing the 'domain' variable... like getting the user id according to the subdomain. Let's say we discoveered that the user id is 1.
            userID = 1;
        }

        if (filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey("Subdomain"))
            filterContext.ActionParameters["SubdomainUser"] = userID;

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

and then your action would be:

```
        [SubdomainFilter]
    public virtual ActionResult GetUserName(int? userID)
    {
        ...
    }
```